# The menu is collapsing out but not in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im using the **accordion-collapse-react-native** library. What I have to do is, when the card is clicked and the menu is opened the arrow icon should change from arrow down to arrow up. The logic that im using is opening and changing the arrow but its not closing anymore. Can u help me to figure out why??

```
const [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(false);
```

```
<Collapse
    style={styles.locationContainer}
    isCollapsed={collapse}
    onToggle={(isCollapsed) => setCollapse({ collapse: isCollapsed })}>
    <CollapseHeader>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCollapse({ collapse: !collapse })}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Zgjedhni lokacionin</Text>
            <View style={styles.friendsContainer}>
                <View style={styles.itemsContainerLocation}>
                    <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Shtëpia e shokut</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.default}>(parazgjedhur)</Text>
                </View>
                {collapse ? (
                    <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-up" size={24} color="black" />
                ) : (
                    <Ionicons name="ios-arrow-down" size={20} color="black" />
                )}
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </CollapseHeader>
    <CollapseBody>
        <View style={styles.adressesContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.adressesName}>Shtëpia ime</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.adressesContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.adressesName}>Shtëpia e prindërve</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.adressesContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.adressesName}>Shtëpia e gjyshit</Text>
        </View>
    </CollapseBody>
</Collapse>
```

Comment: change to : `setCollapse({ collapse: !isCollapsed })`. You are not changing the state.

Comment: You mean in here?  onToggle={(isCollapsed) => setCollapse({ collapse: isCollapsed })}

Comment: yes. your `collapse` variable becomes `false`, but never becomes `true`

Comment: Still not working maybe the problem is here onPress={() => setCollapse({ collapse: !collapse })}

Comment: try, `onClick`instead of `onPress` also please do `console.log(collapse)` to help yourself to track the current value.

Answer (score 1):

Your accordion-collapse-react-native component looks like the exemple in the doc (and this is not a reproach), the only difference is that you are using usestate hook and the exemple is a Class component so the managing state syntax change a bit.
Instead of  `onToggle={(isCollapsed) => setCollapse({ collapse: isCollapsed })}>` try `onToggle={(isCollapsed) => setCollapse(  isCollapsed )}`
And instead of `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCollapse({ collapse: !collapse })}>` try `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCollapse( !collapse )}>`